# "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64" when using Firebase C++ sdk

Tags: c++, firebase

I downloaded the firebase c++ sdk, 10 jun 2016.
I added the sdk into my iOS project, set the -objc into the other linker flags. And i got a linker error
PLease advice.

The error log is as follows:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libapp.a(app_ios_efc96a6f6f98f7443dddf841f7396489.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIROptions", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libapp.a(app_ios_efc96a6f6f98f7443dddf841f7396489.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

(EDIT 1)
Framework search path:

```
 $(PROJECT_DIR)/ios/Libs/Firebase
```

The firebase is in the folder and the includes and the .a libraries.

Comment: show your framework paths in build settings

Comment: @Shubhank, does the framework path have any issues with the linker error? I tried removing the code the calls the Firebase code in c++ and there is no linker error. I tried using the 'file' command in terminal to check if the library have the arm64 architecture and it exist. Im not sure why my project is having this issue.

Comment: @EugeneLim How did you solve this?

Comment: @kgaidis, i used the objective c version instead. and use a c++ wrapper  over it. No response from firebase support on this matter so far.

Answer (score 1):

My problem when I got the same error was that I did not include the iOS SDK along with the C++ library. I did not realize that the C++ library DEPENDS on iOS SDK.

I thought that the the C++ library is a whole new code base that provides the potential for cross-platform development. However, you are still bound to only iOS or Android, but you can choose to code in C++ so you could reuse the C++ code in iOS and Android.

Comment: Well i download the c++ sdk package, It have the frameworks and library's .a file. I include both of them and it gave me this error. 
I tried the iOS package and it works fine. 
And i did follow the steps on the firebase website tutorial.