# Undefine symbols for architecture x86_64 ( cocos2d-x samples for the Firebase C++ SDK)

Tags: c++, firebase, cocos2d-x

I am working a cocos2dx project and trying to integrate ***Firebase C++ SDK*** in my project as below.

I have been following the instruction from [Firebase Cocos2d-x Samples](https://github.com/firebase/cocos2dx-cpp-sample) in GitHub provided by Google for integrating some **Firebase FIREBASE_FEATURE** in a Cocos2dx project. I followed all step successfully but when I build and run, I have been facing ***Linker error*** for *Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64* like below picture

[image]

Anyone facing this problem like me?

### Question:

**Would you please tell me why this is happening and how I solve that? Is there any problem in Sample Project which is  provided by Google?**

N.B: I searched google and found some answer but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the IOS SDK for firebase? As mentioned on this [StackOverFlow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37739250/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64-when-using-firebase-c-sdk), the issue was solved after adding the iOS firebase sdk to the project.